# Edited Sudoers file and Relocated Items

Tags: macos, catalina, sudo

I had to edit my `sudoers` file on Sierra or High Sierra (I don't remember which one.) After updating to 10.15, I have the `Relocated Items` folder and I was able to delete the `sudoers` but I can't delete the rest of the folders in it. When I try to delete it, I get the error `(File Name) can't be modified or deleted because it's required my macOS.` Please let me know if I'm good to delete these files and how to do it if I can. (The `sudoers` files was deleted successfully.)

[image: Image of the files in the folder.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files randomly disappeared and I think it's because I updated to Big Sur so I think that's what fixed it.